# Determing taylor series from other series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

Consider $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(3x^2)$. How to determine the latter's Taylor series from the formers at $a = 0$?

I'd write $$\cos{x} = \sum_0^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Now, I could just insert $3x^2$ instead of $x$, but how do I know if the series that result  from this is actually the taylor series for $\cos{3x^2}$ ? Is this always true?

Comment: This will indeed work. But note you have to write $n=0$ under the sigma, not just 0.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x->3x^2$ and then:
$$\cos{3x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(3x^2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{9^nx^{4n}}{(2n)!}$$

Taylor series is unique, so this series is indeed the taylor series of $\cos{3x^2}$.